# Advanced/label classes in gvSIG 2.4

Tags: labeling, gvsig

New to gvSIG and trying to get SQL filters to work. I can get labels to draw for all features the same way, but when I try to define label classes with filters nothing will draw. I'm trying to label street centerline data based upon a roadway type (Interstate, local, etc)

My condition field is an integer and the filters are:

[image: stroads_2=104 & stroads_2 IN (100, 101, 102, 103, 121)]

Update: I've tried joining my numeric values to a table to bring text values over (i.e. my filter now reads 'dm_description='Interstate',etc. Still, the label classes are not being honored.

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

for the SQL sentence you have to use this format:

FIELD='Value of the field'

when you use Text fields. Here you can see an example where I've used different types of labels depending on the "COMARCA" value:

[image]